# removing parent array and pairing up its inner arrays values

Tags: php, arrays

here is my array

```
$array =   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => crud_inputs[id]
                [value] => id_Value
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => crud_inputs[user_id][]
                [value] => userid_Value
            )


        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => crud_inputs[details]
                [value] => details_value
            )

    )
```

i want to remove parent array ( `$array` ) and pair the 
`[name]=[value]`
in each inner array

i want to end up with a 
`crud_inputs` array

i.e

```
    $crud_inputs[id]         = id_Value ;
    $crud_inputs[user_id][] = userid_Value ;
    $crud_inputs[details]    = details_value ;
```

-
    I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS AT THE END

```
$MY_ORM->UPDATE( $table ,  $crud_inputs );
```

this is what i wrote so far but it doesn't work , i get a empty array at the end

```
$crud_inputs = array();
foreach($array as $ar )
{
  $$ar['name'] =  $ar['value'];
}

var_dump($crud_inputs);
```

@Wrikken ,  =========================================================

this is exactly what i get as my raw array

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'crud_inputs[id]' (length=15)
      'value' => string 'id_Value' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'crud_inputs[user_id][]' (length=22)
      'value' => string 'userid_Value' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'crud_inputs[user_id][]' (length=22)
      'value' => string 'userid_Value2' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'implode[user_id]' (length=16)
      'value' => string ',' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'crud_inputs[date]' (length=18)
      'value' => string 'date_value' (length=13)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'crud_inputs[ip]' (length=15)
      'value' => string 'ip_value' (length=13)
```

-

and this is how i handle it

```
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
            $new[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
    }
    $item = $new;
   var_dump($item);
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `foreach` loop, or doesn't that do the trick for you?

Comment: do you have any control over the names being passed in?

Comment: @Wrikken no it doesn't work , i've added my code at the end

Comment: @RickBurgess not really they dynamically change , it's a crud system that i'm working on

Comment: @JoshAustin i've edited my post(look at the end of my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what was meant as a GET or POST array? `parse_str` helps:

```
$array = ...your array...
foreach($array as &$item){
     $item = array_map('urlencode',$item);
     $item = implode('=',$item);
}
$string = implode('&',$array);
parse_str($string,$result);

var_dump($result);

//and if I read the rest right:
foreach($result['implode'] as $key =>$value){
     $result['crudinputs'][$key] = implode($value,$result['crudinputs'][$key]);
}
```

---

Earlier on:

Bad oneliner (your colleagues will hate you):

```
foreach($array as &$item){
        $item = call_user_func_array('array_combine',call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive',$item));
}
```

Readable multiliner (everybody happy):

```
foreach($array as &$item){
        $new = array();
        foreach($item as $value){
                $new[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
        }
        $item = $new;
}
```

This is assuming an array with *multiple* items if I read your code correctly, so like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => key0
                    [value] => value0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => key1
                    [value] => value1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => key2
                    [value] => value2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => key3
                    [value] => value3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
             .... more items here
```

If not (you only have 1 item), you can omit the outer `foreach`  loop in both examples.

Comment: thnak you , i only needed 1 foreach by mistake added two in my code ! i'm going to give it a try

Comment: it works pretty good but still there's one extra outer array , now i end up with `Array([crud_inputs[key0]] => value0)` not `crud_inputs[key0] => value0`

Comment: So, `$item =$item['crudinputs']` in the end? Or am I missing something about your input array? [see this example of running code in codepad](http://codepad.org/QUX4QFXA).

Comment: now it's `$item['crud_inputs[key0]'] , $item['crud_inputs[key1]']`  at the end ... you see , $item is wrapping my array .... btw i've removed outer foreach `foreach($array as &$item){` in your example ... check out the last part of my post

Comment: Hmff... could you paste op codepad what your exact full input array is?

Comment: I can't look at it till tomorrow though... I hear my bed calling out to me ;)

Comment: thank you very much it works great (nice touch on the implode , you got it right )